# Command MappingModelCompile emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

When I build my project, I get the following errors from Core Data:
[image: Command MappingModelCompile emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure]
It still builds successfully, my app runs, but I wonder where do the errors come from and how can I get rid of them?

UPD: When you expand the above error, you can see the following:

```
CoreData: error: Executing as effective user 501
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***/SourcePackages/checkouts/***-sdk-ios/Sources/***SDK/Resources/Model.xcmappingmodel/xcmapping.xml
CoreData: error: ---------------------------
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       113216 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      43162361
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        501
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: -
CoreData: error:   444
CoreData: error:   file is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error: Information for file system
CoreData: error: ---------------------------
CoreData: error:   File system type:        0x1a
CoreData: error:   File system flags:       0x4909080
CoreData: error:   MNT_JOURNALED
CoreData: error:   Total data blocks:       59840624
CoreData: error:   Free data blocks:        6096129
CoreData: error:   Free blocks for nonsuperuser:    6096129
CoreData: error:   Total i-nodes:           247099491
CoreData: error:   File system ID:      0x1000011, 0x1a
CoreData: error:   Free i-nodes:            243845160
CoreData: error:   Owner UID:           0
CoreData: error:   Filesystem type name:        apfs
CoreData: error:   Mount on name:           /System/Volumes/Data
CoreData: error:   Mount from name:         /dev/disk3s5
2023-07-25 10:38:10.755 mapc[91717:10554306] Attempt to add read-only file at path file:///Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***/SourcePackages/checkouts/***-sdk-ios/Sources/***SDK/Resources/Model.xcmappingmodel/xcmapping.xml read/write. Adding it read-only instead. This will be a hard error in the future; you must specify the NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption.
Command MappingModelCompile emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

Just to check things out I've tried adding `description.isReadOnly = true` to my `NSPersistentStoreDescription`, but in this case only the last error disappears ("Attempt to add read-only file at path..."), the rest are still present, including `Command MappingModelCompile emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure`. The errors are gone only in the case when I delete the mapping model from my Swift Package, but it really isn't the solution because I need it in my Core Data stack.

Comment: So you’re doing some kind of migration?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, that's right. Also I forgot to mention that this Core Data stack is in another SPM package, and when I clone it and add to my xcworkspace from the local repo, it builds without errors. But when I specify the exact version and let SPM manage it, it emits these errors.